Cannot install macOS Sonoma to an external SSD on MacBook
I want to install macOS Sonoma from my M3 MacBook Air which runs Sonoma as well on the internal storage. (Specifically macOS version 14.5 on both internal and the one I try to install.)
My goal is to install a second OS to an external Samsung T7 SSD and then run the computer from the external SSD.
But I can't get it to work, I have tried for three days now! :(
I have followed [Troubleshooting] macOS Sonoma Can't Boot From An External Hard Drive without any luck. Basically, you download macOS Sonoma from Appstore and choose the install location to an APFS/GUI formatted external SSD.
This is the error I get when trying to boot from macOS Sonoma installed on an external SSD.

The macOS version on the selected disc must be reinstalled.



Since you still have macOS Sonoma 14.5 on the internal disk, you should be able to skip a third party tutorial and follow Apple exact process to install macOS on an external drive.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/111336


Pay attention to two things (and the first matters for all updates and install):

Which port you connect the drive for the installation


While you're installing macOS on your storage device, it matters which of these ports you use. After installation is complete, you can connect your storage device to any of them.
Mac laptop computer: Use any USB-C port except the leftmost USB-C port when facing the ports on the left side of the Mac.

This port-specificity also holds for DFU type operations which revive or restore a Mac with Apple silicon or the Apple T2 Security Chip.

Which format did you choose when you reach the second step:

I would recommend APFS since you have an SSD. I would also validate the date and time are well correct on the Mac before attempting the next install. You may have a GUID format with APFS, but I probably would erase things entirely with disk utility to ensure it’s correctly formatted and the repair option shows no errors before the next install attempt.

Omg. The macbook air only have usb-ports on the left side. I used the left one closest to the power adapter connection.
Left one here: https://www.apple.com/v/macbook-air/s/images/overview/connectivity/connectivity_right__fxge1xn29amq_large_2x.jpg

Try again with the right - I sure hope this works, I had no clue that existed till just now when I reread the article closely. Samsung T7 should be fine for this and disk utility should complain if it can’t format the drive with the cable and controller you selected.

Thats crazy, lets check again! Thank you!!

It is bonkers…. You’d think the installer could just tell you - hey buddy, try the other port, please.

Yes yes yes, it worked! Crazy thing but it worked. Gah after 2 days. Thank you very very much!

Any idea what the technical reason behind this restriction is ?

No, but that might be an interesting follow on question.

Note that the Apple Support article says an "appropriate" port must be used when doing updates and upgrades.  Bet that catches people out!

Nothing in the spec sheet suggests there's any difference between the two USB ports.

See my edit @Criggie perhaps Apple engineered direct access to the T2 or Secure Enclave on one port. I’ll see if I can dig up anything else relevant.
